# Firebase Angular : How to retrieve and display data?

Tags: angular, firebase

In my firebase. I have this database for my user :

[My Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz3SG.png)

I have this service to manage my users :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../models/user.model';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  users: User[] = [];
  usersSubject = new Subject<User[]>();

  constructor() { }

  emitUsers(){
    this.usersSubject.next(this.users);
  }

  saveUsers(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users').push(this.users);
  }

  getUsers(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users')
    .on('value',(data)=>{
      this.users = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
      this.emitUsers();

    });
  }

  getSingleUser(id:number){
    return new Promise(
      (resolve,reject) =>{
        firebase.database().ref('/users/'+id).once('value').then(
          (data) =>{
            resolve(data.val());
          }, (error) => {
            reject (error);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

  createNewProfile(newUser:User){
    this.users.push(newUser);
    this.saveUsers();
    this.emitUsers();
  }

  removeUser(user:User){
    const userIndexToRemove=this.users.findIndex(
      (userEl)=>{
        if(userEl==user){
          return true;
        }
      }
    );
    this.users.splice(userIndexToRemove,1);
    this.saveUsers();
    this.emitUsers();
  }

}
```

And this component to display a list of my users:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UsersService} from '../services/users.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {User} from '../models/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.scss']
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  users:User[];
  usersSubscription:Subscription;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usersSubscription = this.usersService.usersSubject.subscribe(
      (users:User[])=>{
        this.users=users;
      }
    );
    this.usersService.emitUsers();
    this.usersService.getUsers();
    console.log(this.users);
    }
  }
}
```

And my html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <div class="list-group"
        *ngFor="let user of users | keyvalue async">
        <p> Hello {{user.firstName}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why but, I have 2 user in my database and my output is just : 
"Hello"
"Hello"
and the firstName are not written
Do you have any idea of why ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are passing your users through the `keyvalue` pipe and not using its output.

In your HTML try replacing `user.firstName` with `user.value.firstName`

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. I reply to my own post with more information. When I use the set() method to save my data, it's working (Because the structure of the database is diferent). But I would like to have the unique ID get thanks to the push() method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Database when I use set() method instead of push() to save my data.

[Database with set() method instead of push()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2aAM.png)

It's when I use :

```
  saveUsers(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users').set(this.users);
  }
```

Instead of

```
  saveUsers(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users').push(this.users);
  }
```

And in this case it's working. My output is Hello Ibra and Hello Pires. But my problem in this case is that I don't have the unique id like with push.